# Spark home access denied to Airflow

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, airflow

I am really stuck in this one. I am trying to run in local mode a Spark Submit Operator in Airflow. And while the access right to the needed folder have read and execute right for any user, I have the following error. Any help would be great please.

```
[2020-12-08 11:00:54,456] {base_hook.py:89} INFO - Using connection to: id: spark_local. Host: local[*], Port: None, Schema: None, Login: None, Password: None, extra: XXXXXXXX
[2020-12-08 11:00:54,458] {spark_submit_hook.py:325} INFO - Spark-Submit cmd: /opt/spark/bin/ --master local[*] --name airflow-spark --queue root.default --deploy-mode client /home/ubuntu/market_risk/utils/etl.py
[2020-12-08 11:00:54,463] {taskinstance.py:1150} ERROR - [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/spark/bin/'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 984, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/spark_submit_operator.py", line 187, in execute
    self._hook.submit(self._application)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/spark_submit_hook.py", line 395, in submit
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1364, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/spark/bin/'
```

My setting for Spark connection in Airflow are as follow:

[image: spark_conn_setting_airflow]

In airflow UI, I have not set any environment variables.

Comment: Your spark submit executable has the wrong path, it should be /opt/spark/bin/spark-submit , you missed the last part

Comment: @mck I checked, my spark-submit is in the path you mentioned

Comment: @mck It seems that I could progress by changing the extra to `{"queue":"root.default", "deploy-mode":"client", "spark-home":"/opt/spark/", "spark-binary":"spark-submit", "namespace":"default"}`. I need to debug

Comment: @mck I confirm that I had to change the extra to `{"queue":"root.default", "deploy-mode":"client", "spark-home":"/opt/spark/", "spark-binary":"spark-submit", "namespace":"default"}`. I had other issues after but not related. It is working now